# Prevent custom (broken) html from breaking the rest of the page

Tags: html

The product I work on supports users providing custom descriptions in markdown format (this is new, previously they could only provide raw html). Unfortunately many users have been using this product for years and as a result there are many descriptions that consist of markup that "sort of works" or "works in IE8".

I don't particularly care if their descriptions don't render right because they are broken, what I am concerned about is that the rest of the page shouldn't be broken because of it.

Example broken code

```html
<ul>
</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
</li>
<!-- no closing ul -->
```

**Things I have done to mitigate the effect**

- I remove the following tags: html head body style frameset frame iframe script markdown-rendered
- Surround descriptions with `<markdown-rendered>` as a way to contain the code.

Even with these mitigations, code like the example above still "breaks out". For the above example, a large amount of markup after it shifts inside the ul. What else can I do to "contain" bad markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you inject the invalid markup into the document, it's going to be parsed and repaired to the best of the browser's ability. I would suggest doing this beforehand, and injecting the *result* of this operation, rather than allowing this operation to potentially disrupt your pre-existing structure.

One way in which libraries and frameworks have done this in the past is to create a bit of temporary structure, assign the invalid markup as the *innerHTML*, and then read back out the *innerHTML*:

```js
var markup = clean( "<ul></li><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></li>" );

console.log( markup ); // "<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>"

function clean ( invalid ) {
    var container = document.createElement( "div" );
    return ( container.innerHTML = invalid ), container.innerHTML;
}
```

When the markup is assigned, it will be parsed, repaired, and constructed into actual DOM objects. When we read back out the *innerHTML*, we'll get nice and clean code directly from the browser.

Comment: This works, I updated the page to encode the descriptions inside their `markdown-rendered` tags, then on page load a js function goes through all such tags and decodes+cleans them as above

Comment: Is there any way of making this SEO friendly?